# Singular vs plural verb form when using "[The / What / ...] kind of X ..."

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

I want to write a sentence similar to "The kind of cookies I like is chocolate ones, which includes Oreos."

Is this grammatically correct?  My thinking is the subject ("kind of cookies") is singular, but the above doesn't seem natural in speech. Would it be correct to replace "is" with "are" or "includes" with "include" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the singular verb if the noun that follows is uncountable

- The only kind of *cheese* I can digest, *is* Parmesan.
  The kind of *music* he plays *is* heavy-metal.

In the OP's example, “cookies” are countable and plural, ergo

> The kind of *cookies* I like **are** chocolate ones, which **include** Oreos.

If we rephrase the sentence, it becomes clearer why the plural is more appropriate:

> The kind of cookies I like ***are** made* from chocolate.

Using the singular form, "is", would be considered ungrammatical by many speakers.